# How to improve a MYSQL Query with multiple JOINS

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have 2 search pages that are super slow in getting results.

I did not write the queries, but I know they are not written in an efficient way; I just do not have enough practice in MYSQL to figure out how to make them more efficient.

What should I do to improve the following query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id AS memberID , m.login , m.age , p.gender
 , p.name AS header , p.id AS profileID , p.city , p.state , p.lastlogin
 , o.login AS online , c.name AS country , ph.filename_1 AS pic 
FROM dt_members AS m 
INNER JOIN dt_profile_approved AS p ON m.id=p.member_id 
LEFT JOIN dt_privacy AS pv ON m.id=pv.member_id 
INNER JOIN dt_countries AS c ON c.id=p.country 
LEFT JOIN dt_photos AS ph ON m.id=ph.member_id 
LEFT JOIN dt_usersonline AS o ON m.login=o.login 
WHERE p.status=1 AND (pv.unsearchable IS NULL OR pv.unsearchable='') 
AND p.gender='Female' AND m.age BETWEEN 25 AND 40 
ORDER BY p.lastlogin DESC 
LIMIT 0, 21;
```

it is terribly slow and showing 500 error often.

Output of explain:

[image: EXPLAIN RESULTS]

Show Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `dt_members` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `login` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `pswd` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `looking_for` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ip_addr` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reg_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `system_status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `system_status_end` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `unlimited` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `unlimited_end` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `matchfinder` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `login` (`login`),
 KEY `pswd` (`pswd`),
 KEY `email` (`email`),
 KEY `name` (`name`),
 KEY `gender` (`gender`),
 KEY `age` (`age`),
 KEY `country` (`country`),
 KEY `looking_for` (`looking_for`),
 KEY `ip_addr` (`ip_addr`),
 KEY `reg_date` (`reg_date`),
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `system_status` (`system_status`),
 KEY `system_status_end` (`system_status_end`),
 KEY `unlimited` (`unlimited`),
 KEY `unlimited_end` (`unlimited_end`),
 KEY `matchfinder` (`matchfinder`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=29150 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

 CREATE TABLE `dt_profile` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `member_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `gender` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `birth_day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `birth_month` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `birth_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `marital_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `children` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `drinking` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `smoking` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `food` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `eye_color` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hair_color` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `body_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `race` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `religion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `occupation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `education` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang_1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang_1_rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang_2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang_2_rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang_3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang_3_rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang_4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lang_4_rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `looking_for` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `age_from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `age_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `general_info` text,
 `appearance_info` text,
 `looking_for_info` text,
 `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `finish_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `not_newbie` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastlogin` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `zipcode` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `photo_pass` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `view_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `wants_kids` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `kids_okay` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `relocate_domestic` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `relocate_international` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `pioneer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `member_id` (`member_id`),
 KEY `country` (`country`),
 KEY `state` (`state`),
 KEY `city` (`city`),
 KEY `email` (`email`),
 KEY `name` (`name`),
 KEY `gender` (`gender`),
 KEY `birth_day` (`birth_day`),
 KEY `birth_month` (`birth_month`),
 KEY `birth_year` (`birth_year`),
 KEY `marital_status` (`marital_status`),
 KEY `children` (`children`),
 KEY `drinking` (`drinking`),
 KEY `smoking` (`smoking`),
 KEY `food` (`food`),
 KEY `eye_color` (`eye_color`),
 KEY `hair_color` (`hair_color`),
 KEY `height` (`height`),
 KEY `body_type` (`body_type`),
 KEY `race` (`race`),
 KEY `religion` (`religion`),
 KEY `occupation` (`occupation`),
 KEY `education` (`education`),
 KEY `lang_1` (`lang_1`),
 KEY `lang_1_rate` (`lang_1_rate`),
 KEY `lang_2` (`lang_2`),
 KEY `lang_2_rate` (`lang_2_rate`),
 KEY `lang_3` (`lang_3`),
 KEY `lang_3_rate` (`lang_3_rate`),
 KEY `lang_4` (`lang_4`),
 KEY `lang_4_rate` (`lang_4_rate`),
 KEY `looking_for` (`looking_for`),
 KEY `age_from` (`age_from`),
 KEY `age_to` (`age_to`),
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `finish_status` (`finish_status`),
 KEY `not_newbie` (`not_newbie`),
 KEY `lastlogin` (`lastlogin`),
 KEY `zipcode` (`zipcode`),
 KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
 KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
 KEY `photo_pass` (`photo_pass`),
 KEY `view_count` (`view_count`),
 KEY `wants_kids` (`wants_kids`),
 KEY `kids_okay` (`kids_okay`),
 KEY `relocate_domestic` (`relocate_domestic`),
 KEY `relocate_international` (`relocate_international`),
 KEY `pioneer` (`pioneer`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=18389 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `dt_privacy` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `member_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `online_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `vkiss_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `profiles_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `IM_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `featured_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `HL_messaged_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `HL_im_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `HL_viewed_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `HL_kissed_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `HL_favorite_yn` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `unsearchable` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `member_id` (`member_id`),
 KEY `online_yn` (`online_yn`),
 KEY `vkiss_yn` (`vkiss_yn`),
 KEY `profiles_yn` (`profiles_yn`),
 KEY `IM_yn` (`IM_yn`),
 KEY `featured_yn` (`featured_yn`),
 KEY `HL_messaged_yn` (`HL_messaged_yn`),
 KEY `HL_im_yn` (`HL_im_yn`),
 KEY `HL_viewed_yn` (`HL_viewed_yn`),
 KEY `HL_kissed_yn` (`HL_kissed_yn`),
 KEY `HL_favorite_yn` (`HL_favorite_yn`),
 KEY `unsearchable` (`unsearchable`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=26305 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `dt_countries` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=226 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `dt_photos` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `member_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `filename_1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `filename_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `filename_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_4` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_6` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_7` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_8` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_9` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_10` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_11` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_12` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_13` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_14` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_15` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_16` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_17` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_18` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_19` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `filename_20` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `private_1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_6` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_7` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_8` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_9` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_10` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_11` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_12` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_13` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_14` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_15` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_16` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_17` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_18` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_19` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `private_20` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_4` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_6` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_7` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_8` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_9` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_10` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_11` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_12` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_13` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_14` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_15` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_16` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_17` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_18` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_19` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description_20` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `filename_12` (`filename_12`),
 KEY `filename_13` (`filename_13`),
 KEY `filename_14` (`filename_14`),
 KEY `filename_15` (`filename_15`),
 KEY `filename_16` (`filename_16`),
 KEY `filename_17` (`filename_17`),
 KEY `filename_18` (`filename_18`),
 KEY `filename_19` (`filename_19`),
 KEY `filename_20` (`filename_20`),
 KEY `member_id` (`member_id`),
 KEY `filename_1` (`filename_1`),
 KEY `filename_2` (`filename_2`),
 KEY `filename_3` (`filename_3`),
 KEY `filename_4` (`filename_4`),
 KEY `filename_5` (`filename_5`),
 KEY `filename_6` (`filename_6`),
 KEY `filename_7` (`filename_7`),
 KEY `filename_8` (`filename_8`),
 KEY `filename_9` (`filename_9`),
 KEY `filename_10` (`filename_10`),
 KEY `private_1` (`private_1`),
 KEY `private_2` (`private_2`),
 KEY `private_3` (`private_3`),
 KEY `private_4` (`private_4`),
 KEY `private_5` (`private_5`),
 KEY `private_6` (`private_6`),
 KEY `private_7` (`private_7`),
 KEY `private_8` (`private_8`),
 KEY `private_9` (`private_9`),
 KEY `private_10` (`private_10`),
 KEY `private_11` (`private_11`),
 KEY `private_12` (`private_12`),
 KEY `private_13` (`private_13`),
 KEY `private_14` (`private_14`),
 KEY `private_15` (`private_15`),
 KEY `private_16` (`private_16`),
 KEY `private_17` (`private_17`),
 KEY `private_18` (`private_18`),
 KEY `private_19` (`private_19`),
 KEY `private_20` (`private_20`),
 KEY `password` (`password`),
 KEY `description_1` (`description_1`),
 KEY `description_2` (`description_2`),
 KEY `description_3` (`description_3`),
 KEY `description_4` (`description_4`),
 KEY `description_5` (`description_5`),
 KEY `description_6` (`description_6`),
 KEY `description_7` (`description_7`),
 KEY `description_8` (`description_8`),
 KEY `description_9` (`description_9`),
 KEY `description_10` (`description_10`),
 KEY `description_11` (`description_11`),
 KEY `description_12` (`description_12`),
 KEY `description_13` (`description_13`),
 KEY `description_14` (`description_14`),
 KEY `description_15` (`description_15`),
 KEY `description_16` (`description_16`),
 KEY `description_17` (`description_17`),
 KEY `description_18` (`description_18`),
 KEY `description_19` (`description_19`),
 KEY `description_20` (`description_20`),
 KEY `filename_10_2` (`filename_10`),
 KEY `filename_10_3` (`filename_10`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11174 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

 CREATE TABLE `dt_usersonline` (
 `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `timestamp` int(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `login` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `userid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id_2` (`id`),
 KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
 KEY `ip` (`ip`),
 KEY `login` (`login`),
 KEY `userid` (`userid`),
 KEY `session_id` (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4424348 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: First of all, you should run an `EXPLAIN` on them (and perhaps post the results here).

Comment: as said, run it thru explain, then do `show create table dt_members ` and the like for each table. Publish those findings. We come back and help.

Comment: @BK435 sorry I am going back to see how to get the full create table info

Comment: @paul I think you should consider how many rules of basic database design you are breaking before moving on to optimizing your queries...You have completely ignored the cardinal rule of normal form (1NF)...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @BK435 I updated with the full data.. I did not write the code but I will read that over for sure. I am trying to fix somebody else's mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `dt_members` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,...

    CREATE TABLE `dt_photos` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `member_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,..
```

You are joining on your query as:

`LEFT JOIN dt_photos AS ph ON m.id=ph.member_id`

Notice how every other time you join on `member_id` to `m.id` the column looks like `member_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL`.  Your join criteria should be on the same data type, otherwise it looks like it is doing a full table scan. It's not using the key because it believes that it has to scan the `varchar` field rather than utilizing indexes for on clause.

Try [Altering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) column `member_id` to that of `m.id` from `dt_members`

It is interesting to note, had you actually tried to create a foreign key constraint, it would not have allowed you to because of the mismatched data types...

Warning: `MYISAM` table will be locked during the duration of the later table process.

Comment: On a similar note, the `login` fields, while they are both matching varchar, have no unique constraints in either table.

Comment: Sorry BK435 but I am a little lost on what you want me to try. its getting late and I will read over everything tomorrow.

Do you want me to alter the TABLE dt_photos? or do you want me to modify the Query?

Comment: if there is a way to modify the QUERY I would prefer that method otherwise the code that writes to these tables would need to be updated in many places

Comment: try changing column member_id to that of m.id from dt_members

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure what you were getting at before. I modified the table structure to int(11) rather than varchar(255) and all is well search results return in less than a second now. 

Crazy I didn't think something like that could effect the Query so much!

Comment: You maybe able to optimize more. Still sounds like it is taking more time than it should...I believe that file sort on dt_members is hindering performance...however, I digress...You should really consider your `schema!` when you have a chance cause that is a hairy mess...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like most of the selectivity on your query is on your `dt_profile_approved` table.  Try creating a compound index on `(status, gender, lastlogin)`

This should allow an index-only selection and ordering.

Your query does the notorious `SELECT a lot ORDER BY something DESC LIMIT tinynumber` pattern. This is expensive.  Try a deferred join.  Start by getting the interesting items from your `dt_profile_approved` table, like this:

```
                 SELECT member_id, lastlogin
                   FROM dt_profile_approved
                  WHERE status=1 
                    AND gender='Female' 
               ORDER BY lastlogin DESC
```

This subquery can be optimized very cleanly with a compound index on `(status, gender, lastlogin, member_id)`. That's called a covering index. It has a great benefit: no extra sorting is required, because the index is already sorted.

Based on the exact query you showed us, the order in the index of `gender` and `status` doesn't matter. But I guess you have another query that looks for males, and you may have one that omits that. So status is likely to be the more selective field across all your queries. (Guessing.)

Then, join that subquery into the rest of your query... that will look something like this.

```
      SELECT DISTINCT 
             m.id AS memberID , m.login , m.age,
             p.gender. p.name AS header , p.id AS profileID , 
             p.city , p.state , p.lastlogin,
             o.login AS online , 
             c.name AS country , ph.filename_1 AS pic 
        FROM (
                 SELECT member_id, lastlogin
                   FROM dt_profile_approved
                  WHERE status=1 
                    AND gender='Female' 
               ORDER BY lastlogin DESC 
             ) AS sel
 INNER JOIN dt_profile_approved AS p ON sel.member_id = p.member_id
 INNER JOIN dt_members AS m  ON m.id=sel.member_id
  LEFT JOIN dt_privacy AS pv ON m.id=pv.member_id 
 INNER JOIN dt_countries AS c ON c.id=p.country 
  LEFT JOIN dt_photos AS ph ON m.id=ph.member_id 
  LEFT JOIN dt_usersonline AS o ON m.login=o.login 
      WHERE (pv.unsearchable IS NULL OR pv.unsearchable='') 
        AND m.age BETWEEN 25 AND 40 
   ORDER BY sel.lastlogin DESC 
      LIMIT 0, 21;
```

If this works, it will be because it can limit the labor of sorting using the index.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving where conditions into the corresponding join condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id AS memberID , m.login , m.age , p.gender
 , p.name AS header , p.id AS profileID , p.city , p.state , p.lastlogin
 , o.login AS online , c.name AS country , ph.filename_1 AS pic 
FROM dt_members AS m 
INNER JOIN dt_profile_approved AS p ON m.id=p.member_id 
   AND p.status=1 AND p.gender='Female' -- Moved from WHERE clause
LEFT JOIN dt_privacy AS pv ON m.id=pv.member_id
   AND (pv.unsearchable IS NULL OR pv.unsearchable='') -- Moved from WHERE clause
INNER JOIN dt_countries AS c ON c.id=p.country 
LEFT JOIN dt_photos AS ph ON m.id=ph.member_id 
LEFT JOIN dt_usersonline AS o ON m.login=o.login 
WHERE m.age BETWEEN 25 AND 40 
ORDER BY p.lastlogin DESC 
LIMIT 0, 21;
```

While where conditions are made *after* all joins, join conditions are evaluated during the join, so vast numbers of unnecessary joins can be avoided early.

Although *theoretically* the query optimizer should do this for you, I have found the mysql can be particularly dense in this regard.

Comment: It is worth noting that moving a condition from the `WHERE` into a `LEFT JOIN`s `ON` can change the result quite a bit. In this case, he is going to get results even if they have pv.unsearchable = 'x', he just won't see the 'x'.